# How can I use Miniblink as a JavaFX component?

Tags: java, c++, javafx, java-native-interface, jna

[Miniblink](https://github.com/weolar/miniblink49) is a streamlined and compact browser control based on Chromium. Someone [used JNI to integrate Miniblink into Java](https://github.com/xjboss/java-miniblink).

Miniblink provides a node.dll, which can be accessed from Java using JNA. I want to integrate it into JavaFX, but I have no idea how I might do this. I want it to be a component similar to `javafx.scene.web.WebView`.

Here is an implementation using C++ and the Windows API.

```cpp
// mb.cpp : 定义应用程序的入口点。
//
 
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "mb.h"
 
//ui
#include "wke.h"
wkeWebView m_web;
 
#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100
 
// 全局变量: 
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // 当前实例
TCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // 标题栏文本
TCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // 主窗口类名
 
// 此代码模块中包含的函数的前向声明: 
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
 
int APIENTRY _tWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);
 
    // TODO:  在此放置代码。
    MSG msg;
    HACCEL hAccelTable;
 
    // 初始化全局字符串
    LoadString(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadString(hInstance, IDC_MY, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);
 
    // 执行应用程序初始化: 
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
 
    hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_MY));
 
    // 主消息循环: 
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
 
    return (int) msg.wParam;
}
 
 
 
//
//  函数:  MyRegisterClass()
//
//  目的:  注册窗口类。
//
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;
 
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
 
    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_MY));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));
 
    return RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
}
 
//
//   函数:  InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int)
//
//   目的:  保存实例句柄并创建主窗口
//
//   注释: 
//
//        在此函数中，我们在全局变量中保存实例句柄并
//        创建和显示主程序窗口。
//
HWND m_wkeHwnd;
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   HWND hWnd;
 
   hInst = hInstance; // 将实例句柄存储在全局变量中
 
   hWnd = CreateWindow(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
 
 
   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);
   //绑定ui
   wkeInitialize();
   RECT rtClient;
   GetClientRect(hWnd, &rtClient);
   rtClient.top += 0;
   m_web = wkeCreateWebWindow(WKE_WINDOW_TYPE_CONTROL, hWnd, rtClient.left, rtClient.top, rtClient.right - rtClient.left, rtClient.bottom - rtClient.top);
   wkeLoadFile(m_web, "ski/index.html");
   //获取hwnd
   m_wkeHwnd = wkeGetHostHWND(m_web);
  // jsBindFunction("123", js_msgBox, 2);//JS调用C++
   wkeShowWindow(m_web, TRUE);
   return TRUE;
}
 
//
//  函数:  WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  目的:    处理主窗口的消息。
//
//  WM_COMMAND  - 处理应用程序菜单
//  WM_PAINT    - 绘制主窗口
//  WM_DESTROY  - 发送退出消息并返回
//
//
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int wmId, wmEvent;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;
 
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        wmId    = LOWORD(wParam);
        wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);
        // 分析菜单选择: 
        switch (wmId)
        {
        case IDM_ABOUT:
            DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
            break;
        case IDM_EXIT:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        // TODO:  在此添加任意绘图代码...
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    case WM_SIZE:{
        int nHeight = HIWORD(lParam);
        int nWidth = LOWORD(lParam);
        MoveWindow(m_wkeHwnd, 0, 0, nWidth, nHeight, TRUE);
    }
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
 
// “关于”框的消息处理程序。
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
 
    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd love to help but I don't understand your question.  You need to scope it more narrowly, perhaps ask a specific question.  Your question seems to be basically "I don't understand JNA, help me."  What specific thing do you need help with? LInking the library? Mapping a function?   What have you tried?

Comment: OK, this seems more a javafx question than a JNA one so hopefully someone else can offer advice.